# Appending to a JQuery variable/object

Tags: jquery, append

I need to append to a DOM object - but I don't know in advance which object that will be (depends what the user selects in the UI). So I must generate the id dynamically and then append - but I'm struggling to find a way to do this.

For example, to append to a table with an id of `my-table-13` I'd like to do something like this:

```
var $Table = 'my-table-' + value;

$(Table)
    .append($("<tr>")
        .attr('id','my-row'));
```

I've tried variations of inserting brackets and #'s on the first line - but no success. Is this possible?

Comment: If your variable is `$Table` then the jQuery would start with `$($Table)`, not `$(Table)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var table = '#my-table-' + value; // or '.my-table-'
```

and then

```
$(table).....
```

`$Table` is a valid variable name in javascript, so `$Table` and `Table` used in `$(Table)` are different.
You were actually trying to use `$(undefined)`...

Using something like `$($Table)` works but it's considered bad syntax.

Comment: if the table variable is the id make sure to add '#' to the selector as well. '#my-table-' + value

Comment: Both answers show valid solutions which I'm grateful for - giving this the vote for the slightly greater detail.

Answer (score 0):

You need a `#` to grab an ID, also reference `$Table` not `Table`

```
var $Table = 'my-table-' + value;

$("#" + $Table)
    .append($("<tr>")
        .attr('id','my-row'));
```